# defining type BT_ADDR in ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-2.5

After trying some simple OS BT functions, I suspcect my def of `BT_ADDR` is not right. It's as follows. I am new to ctypes, can anyone give me some hint ? Are my defs correct ? I am on python2.5 (depricated, yes, hardware constraint)

```
UCHAR = c_ubyte
ULONGLONG = c_ulonglong

# typedef ULONGLONG bt_addr, *pbt_addr, BT_ADDR, *PBT_ADDR;
BT_ADDR = ULONGLONG

# int BthGetCurrentMode(  BT_ADDR* pba,  unsigned char* pmode);
BthGetCurrentMode = windll.btdrt.BthGetCurrentMode 
BthGetCurrentMode.argtypes = [ POINTER( w.BT_ADDR ), POINTER(w.UCHAR) ]

# bt address: dc:1d:30:42:8b:19
bta = c_ulonglong( int('dc1d30428b19', 16) )
print(bta)  
#> c_ulonglong(242017921829657L)
pba = pointer( bta )

pmode = pointer(c_ubyte())
rt = BthGetCurrentMode( pba, pmode )
ec = GetLastError()
print( rt, ec )
#> 1168, 1168
# ERROR_NOT_FOUND = 1168          # Element not found.
```

UPDATE: I updated the code as suggested, but I still get error 1168 on the above function. I tried it on another function as below, it works fine.

```
# int BthRemoteNameQuery(  BT_ADDR* pba,  unsigned int cBuffer,  unsigned int* pcRequired,  WCHAR* szString);
BthRemoteNameQuery = btdrt.BthRemoteNameQuery
BthRemoteNameQuery.argtypes = [ POINTER(w.BT_ADDR),  w.UINT , POINTER(w.UINT),  POINTER(w.WCHAR) ]
cBuffer = 256
pcRequired = pointer( c_uint() )
szString = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer( 256 )
rt = BthRemoteNameQuery( pba, cBuffer, pcRequired ,szString )
ec = GetLastError()
if rt != 0 :
    print( "Rt%s, Err%s" % (rt,ec)  )
else:
    print( 'returned length=', pcRequired.contents )
    print( 'string=', szString.value )
#>13
#>u'QR-386A-8B19'
```

Comment: `BT_ADDR = ULONGLONG`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. It's this poor function that is not working.